# How to get a list of requests from the MockServerContainer

Tags: testcontainers

I want to use a MockServerContainer to mock a webhook site.

My current code will make a request to that webhook while I'm executing it. On the test, I do expect to get 3 requests to it with different bodies. The test I want to make is to run the code and check if I have the 3 requests to the MockServerContainer with the expected bodies.

I need a method from the test containers that retrieves all the requests registered on the Mockserver. Is there any?

Answer (score 1):

In the end, it was not so hard to find the solution. But maybe I could save someone half an hour.

My main error was focusing on the MockServerContainer instead of the client. The client has a really nice method ([retrieveRecordedRequests](https://javadoc.io/static/org.mock-server/mockserver-client-java/5.14.0/org/mockserver/client/MockServerClient.html#retrieveRecordedRequests-org.mockserver.model.RequestDefinition-)) that makes what I need.

In the end I do need to store the client:

```
public class NotificationContainer {


    public static final MockServerContainer server =
            new MockServerContainer(DockerImageName.parse("jamesdbloom/mockserver")
                    .withTag("mockserver-5.5.4"));
    public static MockServerClient client;


    public static String getUrl() {
        return server.getEndpoint();
    }

    public void callAfterStartSever() {
            ContainerUtils.waitFor(server, Duration.ofSeconds(10));
            NotificationContainer.client = new MockServerClient(server.getHost(), server.getServerPort());
            client.when(HttpRequest.request())
                    .respond(HttpResponse.response());
    }
}
```

And then use it on the test so I get the responses

```
@Test
void checkWebhook(){
    //Do the call that makes the webhooks
    val responses = NotificationContainer.client.retrieveRecordedRequests(null);
    //validate the request are the expected ones
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution. I'd say this is a general pattern for using Testcontainers. For interacting with the containerized application itself, just use the usual clients.